# Find Missing multiple numbers sequence in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

My table is like this:

```
DrawDate    num    DrawName    etc...
2015-08-01  2      Draw 2
2015-08-01  3      Draw 3
2015-08-02  1      Draw 1
2015-08-02  2      Draw 2
2015-08-02  4      Draw 4
2015-08-03  3      Draw 3
2015-08-04  1      Draw 1
2015-08-04  2      Draw 2
2015-08-04  3      Draw 3
2015-08-04  4      Draw 4
```

i would like to get the missing sequence number (num column) in the Table.
How could i achieve this?

I had find so many solutions but there are drawbacks of not including start number or the hardcoding the first and last number for sequence. But i could not hardcode there any value. Start value is specified by 1 but no end sequence is defined. it could be 4 as in the table above or in some cases may be 18 or 20 but i need to find the duplicates by drawdate maximum value (the last one).

**Edit**

The Final Result would be

```
DrawDate    missingnum   
2015-08-01    1     
2015-08-02    3      
2015-08-03    1      
2015-08-03    2
```

Comment: Your chances of getting a correct answer would increase greatly if you included in the question the table showing how the final result should look like. Also, what version of SQL Server do you use? Having tags with two versions is confusing. If you need a solution that works with both, say it clearly in the question.

Comment: Which version are you using SQL Server 2008 or 2012?  They have different capabilities.  Also, it your question with your desired results.  It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2008. I had edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess:

```
declare @t table 
(
    DrawDate    date,
    Num         int
)

insert into @t values
('2015-08-01' ,  2 ),
('2015-08-01' ,  3 ),
('2015-08-02' ,  1 ),
('2015-08-02' ,  2 ),
('2015-08-02' ,  4 ),
('2015-08-03' ,  3 ),
('2015-08-04' ,  1 ),
('2015-08-04' ,  2 ),
('2015-08-04' ,  3 ),
('2015-08-04' ,  4 );


with AvailableDates as
(
    select distinct DrawDate from @t
),
AvailableNumbers as
(
    select distinct Num from @t
),
CrossJoined as
(
    select
        DrawDate,
        Num
    from    
        AvailableDates
        cross join AvailableNumbers
)
select
    *
from
    CrossJoined cj
    left join @t t on t.DrawDate = cj.DrawDate and t.Num = cj.Num
where
    t.Num is null;
```

**Edit**

The second guess (after the comment reading):

```
with MaxNumberPerDate as
(
    select DrawDate, MaxNum = max(Num) from @t group by DrawDate
),
N as 
(
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)    
),
Multiplied as
(
    select
        DrawDate,
        Num     =   N.n
    from    
        MaxNumberPerDate md
        inner join N on N.n <= md.MaxNum
)
select
    m.*
from
    Multiplied m
    left join @t t on t.DrawDate = m.DrawDate and t.Num = m.Num
where
    t.Num is null;
```

Comment: Thanks but how could we ignor the number sequence for different dates. e.g. 2015-08-01 has 4 draws with 1 draw missing. And 2015-08-05 has 12 draws but no one missing. Your query will produce the result according to 12 draws and added the other 8 draws as missing.

Comment: I've added the second variant. It outputs the result you mentioned.